# How does System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager find an App.config?

Tags: c#, .net, configurationmanager

My question here is somewhat abstract, specifically about the probing paths used by `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()`. I don't see any notes in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) that address my question, and I hope it is not too ambiguous for this format.

> How do I determine/control which directory `ConfigurationManager` will probe for an app.config?

**Abstract Context**

Consider a testing situation, where

- The test assembly includes an App.config.
- The test assembly uses `ConfigurationManager` to populate expected config values.
- The assembly *being tested* does not have an app.config.
- The assembly *being tested* also uses `ConfigurationManager` to look up values.
- The test is executed from a directory containing both assemblies of interest.
- The test is executed from a directory containing the App.config of interest.

As I approached this setup, I was anticipating that `ConfigurationManager` would probe the `/bin` -- the directory executing my tests.

I'm observing through debugging, however, that

1) In the code of the testing assembly, `ConfigurationManager` is returning my expected section.

2) In the code of the assembly being tested, `ConfigurationManager` is returning `Nothing`.

3) Both calls to `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` are passed the same section name.

This tells me that the code is looking somewhere else for configuration values. I would guess it is controlled by namespace, then? I'm having trouble finding any explicit statements on the probing paths used by [GetSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection(v=vs.110).aspx), beyond

> this method retrieves a configuration file obtained by merging **the** application configuration file ...

This would indicate to me that it is using `MyTestingAssembly.dll.config`, but my observations clash with that understanding.

**Question**

How can I pin down/control the directory from which `ConfigurationManager` will pull values?

Comment: While it can be quite the rabbit hole, you could look at the source for ConfigurationManager http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Configuration/System/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs

Comment: Definitely it is a rabbit hole, and you can find some details from great articles like, https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19675/Cracking-the-Mysteries-of-NET-Configuration#t1_1